# Create and load Modules in OpenCart?

Tags: php, opencart

I want to add a model php file, in new folder in the catalog/model dir.

```
<?php
class ModeloPaginacion extends Model{
    public function contarGarages(){
        $query = $this->db->query ("SELECT COUNT(*)AS total FROM  `" . DB_PREFIX . "vendors`");
        return $query->row['total'];
        //return "29";
    }//fin funcion

}//fin class

?>
```

When I want to load this model in the home.php controller the whole project appear to broke, cuze it doesn't show anything on the browser.
And ther error is generated from the load in the home controller. When I comment does lines, the proyect work just fine.

Can someone help me with this issue??

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are a couple of issues with the above. Firstly, you're not naming your model right, so it's never going to work. So lets assume this is going to be in a folder in `catalog/model/tool/` called `paginacion.php`

You start by defining the model as

```
class ModelToolPaginacion extends Model {
```

then to call it in your controller, you first need to load it and then call it

```
$this->load->model('tool/paginacion');
$this->model_tool_paginacion->contarGarages();
```

Which should work for you. Notice the naming conventions throughout which are all linked (tool and paginacion)